# log4net - Print specific property, not whole collection

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net

Using log4net, I have saved custom information in the following way

```
ThreadContext.Properties["context"] = info;
```

How can I output only this specific property, using the PatternLayout?

If i use `%property` it prints the whole collection like this:

```
{log4net:HostName=wrkst16, context=[my stuff here]}
```

I only want the content of "context" itself though. I tried `%properties['context']`, but it just appends the `['context']` part:

```
{log4net:HostName=wrkst16, context=[my stuff here]}['context']
```

Any way to get only a specific item of the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
%property{context}
```